# Subtraction(list) recursively in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I know how to add the numbers in a list recursively

```
def mysum(L):
    if not L:
        return 0
    else:
        return L[0] + mysum(L[1:])
```

Can you help me to build the subtraction recursively in the same manner(only one input - List).

```
mydiff([10,1,2,3])
```

Many thanks

Comment: I have don it earlier, but i prints wrong result.
In case mydiff([10,1,2,3])  it shows 8. But should be 4

Comment: Are you allowed to use an inner function, i.e. define a function inside `mydiff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the sequence is `(3,2,1)`, the result is 0. But subtraction is going in reverse direction, i.e. `2 -1` than `3 - (2-1)` if you use `return L[0] - mysum(L[1:])`.

So we have to use an accumulator which keeps the difference of first and second element of a sequence.

```
def mydiff(L, acc=None):
    if not L:
        return acc
    else:
        if acc is None:
            acc = L[0] - L[1]
            L = L[2:]
        else:
            acc -= L[0]
            L = L[1:]
        return mydiff(L, acc)
```

More simpler one;

```
def mysub(seq, acc=None):
    seq = iter(seq)
    if acc is None:
        item = next(seq, None)
        if item is None:
            return acc
        acc = item

    item = next(seq, None)
    if item is None:
        return acc
    return mysub(seq, acc - item)
```

Answer (score 1):

The calculation to be done is

```
>>> 10-(1+(2+(3+0)))
4
```

so the first operation is a subtraction, but the rest of the operations remain additions. I think you need to use an inner function if you're not allowed to add a second parameter to the main function:

```
def mydiff(L):
    def sub(L, first=False):
        if not L:
            return 0
        else:
            if first:
                return L[0] - sub(L[1:])
            else:
                return L[0] + sub(L[1:])
    return sub(L, True)
```

Testing:

```
>>> mydiff([10,1,2,3])
4
```

Comment: @DanielYefimov You can see in my example that it does return the result. Why do you think it doesn't?